# UITableViewCell is redrawing on dequeue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, uitableview

**My setup**

I have a `UITableViewCell` that is in my main storyboard in a `UITableViewController`.  It gets populated with some JSON data pulled from a REST API that will cause each cell to be a variable height.  There are `UIImageViews`, `UILabels` all of different heights and styles, think Instagram-esque.

**My problem**

When I scroll to maybe the 5th or 6th cell, then go back up, they start redrawing and overlapping, so text gets mixed, lines get redrawn, etc.

**What I've tried**

This seems like a common problem on SO, so I've tried several posted solutions.  It seems like my issue is probably the same problem as others face, which is, I am calling `addSubview` on my cell every time it dequeues, but I've tried checking to see if the cell already exists.  I came across another post somewhere (sorry, I can't remember where), that suggests that because I am creating this in the storyboard, it is already initialized and `if ( !cell )` will already return false, so I don't know how to prevent it from redrawing.

When I try removing the cell from the storyboard, and creating it programmatically, I get an error saying it can't find a cell with my identifier `@"Cell"`.

I've also tried someone's solution of removing all subviews when I dequeue, so I used:

```
for ( UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews ) {
     if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
         [view removeFromSuperview];
     }
}
```

and it doesn't find anything.

Comment: The simplest solution is to create all your subview in the storyboard so you don't have to add any in code. If you want to add them in code, create a UITableViewCell subclass, and add the subviews in its init method. Adding subviews in cellForRowAtIndexPath is rarely the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks @rdelmar.  How would I do this when I don't know what content will be in there for sure?  I know I'll have an image and at least 2 labels, but I could have additional labels or a button.  Is that why you are suggesting subclassing it?

Comment: If you're adding those extra views based on the indexPath (some rows have them and some don't based on the data source), then you do need to add them in cellForRow. Another solution, if you don't have too many different cell types, is to make multiple cells in the storyboard, and dequeue the appropriate one based on the data source.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try in the morning and get back to you.

Comment: @rdelmar - I couldn't sleep on this, had to try it out, ended up getting it working.  I'm sure it can be improved, but MVP is what I need right now.  Can you post this as an answer so I can check it off, please?

Comment: @rdelmar - Just checking to see if you saw my comment asking you to make your comment an answer so I can mark it as correct.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

@rdelmar's comment is correct. You shouldn't do what you're doing. Might work, but it's bad form and you don't want to get into bad habits.

First, take advantage of object oriented programming. A cell should be able to configure itself based on the data you ask it to display. The table view shouldn't be designing the cell.

UITableViewCells need to be optimized for speed. Creating and adding subviews is a slow process. It's OK to do it once, but the cell will be reused (a system optimization) and you should just reuse the existing views that were added the first time the cell was created.

For example, you can hide subviews if they're not needed. You might want to do this in -prepareForReuse. You can move them around in -layoutSubviews. Or change the position of subviews in -updateConstraints.

Typically you just want to pass the data to display to the table view cell subclass from the data source (often the view controller). Let the cell do the display work.

Comment: Thanks, @dave-batton.  You are correct on both things, 1) rdelmar was correct, 2) I need to make sure I'm not learning bad habits. 

I'm sure I'll pick up a lot of bad habits as I'm figuring this out, but I'll do my best to go through and refactor and pick up best practices. 

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a *new method* in your *cell class* to *reset cell* to its default style and call this method after `dequeueCell`.

Comment: Thanks @britto-thomas, would you be able to elaborate a bit?

Comment: Just set the frames of all the subviews in your cell for a Default Style in a method. Or if you have different styles for your cell add different method to cell design in your custom cell class and call it with you need at the time of before loading.

Comment: One of the problems I'm experiencing is that when I try to iterate through the subviews, nothing seems to be there.  See the last part of my original post for the code I'm trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

When you add your subview after dequeueing uour cell, give a tag to your subview. This way, when you dequeue a cell, you can first check for the presence of a subview with your tag, and if it exists, remove it before adding your new view:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    // try to dequeue a cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:<yourCellIdentifier>];

    if( !cell )
    {
        // create a new cell if necessary
    }

    static int _myViewTag = 1000987 // give it a high int : low value are used by the system in cells

    UIView *v = cell.contentView viewWithTag:_myViewTag];

    if( v ) // subview with such tag already exists, so remove it.
        [v removeFromSuperview];

    // now add your new subview
    [cell.contentView addSubview:<yourView>];

    // adjust height of cell to your view.
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to manage this is to subclass `UITableViewCell` and adding all your required `Views` as properties. So now when a cell comes up for "recycling", you know where to find the old views, like :

```
[cell.myTextLabel setText:@""];
```

aaaand you're done.

**UPDATE** creating a subclass makes sense if you have only a small number of "TYPES" of cells. create a subclass for each. How much complicated it gets depends on your specific scenario. But i've done it and found it to be the most effective method.

**UPDATE 2** or you could make multiple cells in the storyboard, and dequeue the appropriate one based on the data source, save all the coding.